# Flex Bitmapimage Graphic Mouse click error

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I have added a BitmapImage as a Graphic element:

```
var bmp:BitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
var g:Graphic = new Graphic();

g.addElement(bmp);
myCanvas.addChild(g);
```

Now, on Mouse Click event to the left or top of BitmapImage, `event.target` gives `g` as the target instead of the canvas. When I am not clicking the BitmapImage, why is `event.target` pointing to `g`?

Answer (score 0):

The event.target need not always point to the object you clicked on. Use event.currentTarget to get the reference of the object on which the click interaction took place. Pls refer livedocs.adobe.com for more details.